# Why is there no std equivalent of boost::enable_if?

Tags: c++11, boost, stl, template-meta-programming, enable-if

In C++11, `std::enable_if` was added to the Standard Library. It is equivalent to `boost::enable_if_c` whose condition is a `bool`. This is suitable for rather simple conditions, but as soon as you use predicates that hold their result in a `value` constant, you have to use the more verbose construct `my_predicate<MyArgs>::value` to turn it into `bool`.
This is exactly what `boost::enable_if` (without `_c` suffix) was made for.

Why is there no equivalent in Standard Library?

Comment: `typename my_predicate<MyDependentType>::value` what?

Comment: for roughly comparable to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/22/why-doesnt-c-implement-top-level-methods/)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I made a mix between metafunctions returning types and those returning values.

Comment: I meant `boost::enable_if<my_predicate<MyArgs>>` was equivalent to the more verbose `std::enable_if<my_predicate<MyArgs>::value>`.

Comment: IIRC boost folks were surprised and complained to see the committee adopt the bool version as default.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Thank you for understanding my question ;) So do Boost folks keep using `boost::enable_if` rather than `std::enable_if`?

Comment: The committee added _t and _v versions for all their traits to accommodate this. IIRC experimental has detect_t<...> to avoid typename...type

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Thanks. If you turn this into an answer I will accept it! IMHO defining the _v counterpart of every trait is a poorer design than having an exact `boost::enable_if` equivalent. Moreover _v is only C++17 :(

Comment: I was wrong about detected_t. It is just an identity typedef mostly

Comment: I can easily turn the argument on its head: taking a type "is suitable for rather simple conditions, but as soon as you" need to combine predicates "you have to use the more verbose construct" `std::integral_constant<bool, my_predicate1<MyArgs>::value && my_predicate2<MyArgs>::value>` "to turn it into" a type.

Comment: @TC that is just `and_<my_predicate1<MyArgs>, my_predicate2<MyArgs>>`. No more wrapping inside of a `integral_constant` needed

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb You have to standardize `and_` first for that argument to work.

Comment: @T.C. so then your argument is a strawman, because they wouldn't add the alternative (boost) enable_if without tools that make it (more) useful.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Hardly any more strawman than OP's. After all, if you just standardize variable templates and `_v`, bam - no more `::value`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard library goes a different route here. C++17 added variable templates shortcuts for all the type traits that return a `::value`. The pattern is always

```
template <typename... Args>
some_trait_v = some_trait<Args...>::value;
```

For instance you can write

```
std::enable_if<std::is_same_v<T1,T2>>
```

Further the argument for `enable_if` could be the result of `constexpr` expressions, for instance

```
std::enable_if<some_constexpr_function<T1,T2>()>
```

This way is more generic and does not depend on passing something that must have a `value` member.

Comment: Good point with `constexpr`! This is a convincing argument for justifying this choice.